# Ruby or Javascript - Phone Dev and platforms

Tags: javascript, ruby, html

I am new to coding, but I have an idea for a phone app (game) that I want to build. Do you recommend using HTML5 or Ruby for phone development?
It's not going to be a very complex game, a simple mash up of RPG + Telltale if you will. It will also have "minigame" sistem, like in Dumb Ways to Die.
Which language + platform can you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems to be too broad. It can be closed by community.

Comment: You need something like rubymotion or ruboto to make mobile apps, but you can always use ruby and html to make a Web site which one can open on a mobile phones browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up concepts and technologies.

[HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp) is not a programming language like [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)), and Ruby alone doesn't have the means to create an online game.

I would recommend you to follow this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript), which uses pure Javascript for a minimalist game development.